# How to unpack a list of tuples in python and insert into a table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a list of tuples and I want to insert it into a SQL Server table

```
[(1, 1, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 2, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 3, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 4, 4, 0, False),
 (1, 5, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 6, 1, 0, False),
 (2, 1, 4, 0, False),
 (2, 2, 1, 0, False),
 (2, 3, 0, 15, False)]
```

I am also trying to insert a timestamp column

`now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

My final output is

```
col1  col2 col3 col4  col5    timestamp
1       1    0    0   False   2021-04-18 20:16:25
... and so on
```

Comment: Add your attempted code as well

Comment: Look for [`cursor.executemany`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)

Answer (score 1):

You can Just:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\test.db')
stmt = "insert into table_name (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

cur = conn.cursor()
## many rows
vals = [(1, 1, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 2, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 3, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 4, 4, 0, False),
 (1, 5, 0, 0, False),
 (1, 6, 1, 0, False),
 (2, 1, 4, 0, False),
 (2, 2, 1, 0, False),
 (2, 3, 0, 15, False)]

cur.executemany(stmt, vals)
cur.close()
```

Comment: … and if you want to include the current date/time you can use `"insert into table_name (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,[timestamp]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"`

Comment: (Note that the question is tagged `sql-server`, not `sqlite`.)